# Cannot read every character from a file

Tags: python, file-handling

This is from project euler question 18.
I used this method to read from the file "18.txt"
This is my code-

```
f=open("18.txt","r")
grid1=[]
grid=[grid1]
no=0
while f.read(1):
   print(f.read(1))
```

but it doesn't print every number from the file and skips alternative numbers.

18. txt contents-

    75
    95 64
    17 47 82
    18 35 87 10
    20 04 82 47 65
    19 01 23 75 03 34
    88 02 77 73 07 63 67
    99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
    41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
    41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
    53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
    70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
    91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
    63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
    04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23

Comment: Well here you `f.read(1)` something, but "throw away" the result, and then the next `f.read(1)` in the `while` reads the next item, and then prints that value.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to avoid f.read(1) in while statement from throwing away the results. Can you you suggest me a method for reading a single character from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `f.read(1)` *twice* each iteration, once in `while f.read(1)` and again for `print(f.read(1))`. You only print the second character, so you will only see *half* of the data being read.

If you want to see *each character* printed, call `f.read(1)` just **once** each iteration. Store the result in a variable and test against the variable, then print the variable:

```
char = f.read(1)
while char:
    print(char)
    char = f.read(1)
```

You can avoid having to assign to `char` before the loop if you used `while True:` and break out when `f.read(1)` doesn't return data:

```
while True:
    char = f.read(1)
    if not char:
        break
    print(char)
```

or you can use the [`iter()` function with a sentinel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
for char in iter(lambda: f.read(1), ''):
    print(char)
```

If you wanted to read the *numbers* from the file, don't use `f.read(1)`. Just loop over the file and split each line on whitespace:

```
with open("18.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split())
```

You probably want to convert the text to *integers* too, and build up your `grid` list of lists:

```
grid = []
with open("18.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        values = [int(v) for v in line.split()]
        grid.append(values)
```

Comment: Again it is skipping numbers and it's not even reading until last digit. Here's the output I'm getting-    5
9

4
1

7
8


8
3

7
1


0
0

2
4

5
1

1
2

5
0

4
8

2
7

3
0

3
6


9
6

4
2

6
1

0
9


1
4

6
5

3
4

0
7

3
4

8
7

3
4

2
3

6
9

9
5

1
4

5
2

3
9

2
9

1
1


0
1

3
2

7
7

7
7

9
6

7
5


1
7

2
3

7
1

1
4

8
5

7
2

8
6

6
0

8
8

3
6

0
7

6
6

7
4

1
0

2
9

7
2

9
7

8
7

3
3

3
6

4
2

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi: Not with the code I posted. You appear to be using your old version still. And are you reading the file with single characters?

Comment: It is appending values in grid from index 1. grid[0] is empty.

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi: then the first line of your file is empty. Either skip empty lines (`if not line.strip(): continue`) or fix your file.

Comment: @MartjinPieters I am currently using python 3.7.0(v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47). Yeah, actually I wanted to add numbers to grid1 and when f.read(1) gets space it will append into grid1 when f.read(1) gets '\n' grid1 will be appended to grid.

Comment: @ShikharDwivedi: that's a very labour-intensive way of parsing a file, and totally unnecessary in a higher-level language.